# While installing PHP, I came accross 'missing operand' after executing mkdir in Cygwin

Tags: php, cygwin, mkdir

While attempting to make sure that `$CVSROOT` existed, I executed

```
mkdir $CVSROOT
```

only to find the error:

> 'missing operand'

Comment: try: `mkdir("$CVSROOT", 0700);` and if it should be a string not a variable use: `mkdir('$CVSROOT', 0700);`

Comment: The permission, does it works?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I'm going to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

(The number is the permission you set)

```
mkdir("$CVSROOT", 0700);
```

And if it should be a string not a variable use:

```
mkdir('$CVSROOT', 0700);
```